# Linux Device drivers

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am getting started in linux device driver development and I often see this kind of code and am unable to understand what it exactly does:

```
#<linux/fs.h>
loff_t (*llseek) (struct file *, loff_t,int);
```

The llseek method is used to change the read write position in a file.The loff_t is a long offset parameter.
What I dont understand is the above syntax and how it actually works.
Could someone please shed some light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    loff_t (*llseek) (struct file *, loff_t,int);
```

This just says that `llseek` is a pointer to a function that returns a `loff_t` and takes three parameters. The first parameter is a pointer to a `struct file`. The second is a `loff_t`. The third is an `int`.

However, if you look closely, you'll see it appears inside the declaration for `struct file_operations`. This means that `struct file_operations` contains a member called `llseek` that is a pointer to a function that returns a `loff_t` and takes those three parameters.

By the way, if you don't understand how to do OOP programming in C by using things like structures that contain pointers to functions, you really have no business going anywhere near a kernel device driver. (If you're familiar with C++, then just understand that a structure with pointers to functions is basically the way you fake a class in C.)

Comment: The only area I had a doubt was loff_t (*llseek). That seems to be clear now.

Comment: It's not unusual for C++ programmers to be unfamiliar with how OOP is "faked" in C. If you understand C++ classes, you'll get the hang of it quickly. It's a form of polymorphism.